# Is there an alternative to IN with LIMIT?

Tags: mysql

I want to implement a procedure which updates a "high score" or "top 10 scores" in a game.

My idea is to execute the following code:

```sql
DELETE FROM Highscore
 WHERE scoreId NOT IN
   (SELECT scoreId FROM Highscore ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 10)
```

But then I get an error that the version of MySQL I'm using doesn't support `IN` with `LIMIT`.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another workaround for:

```
DELETE FROM Highscore
WHERE scoreId NOT IN
   (SELECT scoreId FROM Highscore ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 10)
```

is to enclose the subquery with the `LIMIT` inside another subquery:

```
DELETE FROM Highscore
WHERE scoreId NOT IN
   (SELECT scoreId FROM 
      (SELECT scoreId FROM Highscore ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 10)
      AS tmp
   )
```

But I think it's best not to combine nested subqueries with references, in the `WHERE` clause, to the same table you want to delete from. I think it's better to use `JOIN`:

```
DELETE h
FROM 
      Highscore AS h
  CROSS JOIN
      ( SELECT scoreId FROM Highscore ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 10
      ) AS tmp
WHERE h.scoreId NOT IN (SELECT scoreId FROM tmp)
```

or even better, if you can make it simpler (and possibly faster with an index on `value`), as it is possible in your case (Note that the following will keep more than 10 rows if there are ties in the 10th place):

```
DELETE h
FROM 
      Highscore AS h
  CROSS JOIN
      ( SELECT value 
        FROM Highscore 
        ORDER BY value DESC 
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET 9
      ) AS tmp
WHERE h.value < tmp.value
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM Highscore ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 10,5
```

That last `5` can be any number. If you run this every time a score is added, you can have it as `1`. To allow for more margin of error, use `10`.

EDIT: Sorry, apparently you can't use an offset here. In that case:

```
DELETE FROM Highscore WHERE value < (SELECT value FROM Highscore ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 10,1)
```

If it doesn't let you do that (select from the same table as an update/delete), try:

```
SET @tmp = (SELECT value FROM Highscore ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 10,1)
DELETE FROM Highscore WHERE value < @tmp
```

EDIT again: As pointed out in comment, causes problems if 11th value is equal to 10th. Try:

```
SET @id = (SELECT scoreId FROM Highscore ORDER BY value DESC, scoreId DESC LIMIT 10,1), @val = (SELECT value FROM Highscore ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 10,1)
DELETE FROM Highscore WHERE value <= @val AND scoreId < @id
```

Ordering by the scoreId in the first variable ensures that when there are several with the same score, no less than 10 will be left there.

Comment: `SET @tmp = (SELECT value FROM Highscore ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 10,1)
DELETE FROM Highscore WHERE value < @tmp` yeah this works buts a little bit buggy (if the 11 row have the same value as row 10)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inserting new rows you could update the existing rows using [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Another way would be to edit the select that gets the highscore. That way you keep track of all the previous highscores aswell. Using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` would let you do such a query.

Comment: r u sure you meant to answer this question?

Comment: UPDATE? mhnm? the row with the lowest score? I don't think thats a good idea. If the game ends, the score of all people sends to the database (The count of people is variable). So i don't know how to use UPDATE in this case

Comment: You can use `LIMIT` with `DELETE`, but not `OFFSET`

Comment: @ypercube I have not mentioned OFFSET in my answer?

Comment: @Marcus: `LIMIT x,y` is the same as `LIMIT y OFFSET x`.

Comment: @ypercube Yes, I'm aware of that. But I don't mention anything about `DELETE` in my answer

Comment: @Marcus: Sorry, I thought you had that (`LIMIT x,y`) and revised. Must have misclicked on the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a MySQL install to test this on, but in TSQL you could do something like

```
delete from HighSchore
where scoreID not in
(select top 10 scoreID from HighScore order by Value desc)
```

Of course,it's better to do this with an outer join instead of a subquery.

Also, in my opinion, you should never delete data like this, but just retrieve the top 10 whenever you need to.

```
select top 10 value
from Highscore
order by Value desc;
```

Comment: mysql does not allow top/limit within inner queries.

Comment: @ItayMoav seriously? I'll leave this here in case anyone needs it for other servers, then.

Comment: We ALL (mysql users) hope this get fixed soon, but sadly, this is the case (may be in the latest versions currently starting to get out it exists, but not sure they are production stable yet).

Comment: `LIMIT` is not allowed in subqueries: `IN\ALL\ANY\SOME (subquery with LIMIT)`. It's allowed in other subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

First, create temporary table of top 10

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_highscores 
    (SELECT scoreId FROM Highscore ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 10);
```

Then, delete those NOT IN top 10

```
    DELETE FROM Highscore WHERE scoreId NOT IN 
    (SELECT scoreId FROM tmp_highscores)
```

And, not to forget: **"scoreId" should be indexed on the 'Highscore' table**