# Using limit in a left join in mysql

Tags: mysql

Guys can you help me with this *not working* query?

```
UPDATE DB_1 
left join blacklist as blk 
    on DB_1.last_email=blk.email 
SET DB_1.sampling = ? 
WHERE blk.email IS NULL 
    and DB_1.sampling IS NULL 
LIMIT "+slot;
```

I need to update 25k row at the time but doing this is not working. How can I create a query that does work? I was thinking to drop the left join and use an IN for the join.

Comment: Check this answer: [Is there an alternative to IN with LIMIT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940440/is-there-an-alternative-to-in-with-limit/7947425#7947425)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you you want to update the rows in `DB_1` that are not in the `blacklist`?

You can try:

```
UPDATE 
    DB_1 
SET 
    DB_1.sampling = ? 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM blacklist AS blk 
        WHERE blk.email = DB_1.last_email
      ) 
ORDER BY  
    <something>
LIMIT 
    <whatever>
```

or:

```
UPDATE 
        DB_1 AS upd
    JOIN
        ( SELECT t.PK
          FROM 
                  DB_1 AS t
              LEFT JOIN 
                  blacklist AS blk 
                      ON blk.email = t.last_email
          WHERE 
              blk.email IS NULL
          ORDER BY  
              <something>
          LIMIT 
              <whatever>
       ) AS lim
           ON lim.PK = upd.PK
SET 
    upd.sampling = ?
```